# Change Buttons text scale in Ursina

Tags: button, scale, ursina

I was just wondering if it is possible to change the text size in the button type entity in Ursina. I haven't found anything like button1.text_scale = … anything is helpful. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Tou can get the Text that's parented to the button with `.text_entity`. You can then transform that as you wish.

This is good if you just want to make it twice as big or something:

```py
button1.text_entity.scale *= 2
```

If you want to set it to a specific size, you can set `.world_scale`:

```py
button1.text_entity.world_scale = .1
```